# How set focus in multiple rows in Jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus

to set focus in multiple rows in table I did:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval( idx1, idx2);
table.requestFocus();
```

I try also

```
table.addRowSelectionInterval( idx1, idx2);
```

But I did not find a result.

Finally I tried:

```
table.requestFocus();
table.changeselection(row, col, true, false)
```

But I cannot  select multiple rows like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVIt2.png]

- rows 2 and 3 is selected and the focus in row 2.

Comment: Focus is a singular thing. It can be in exactly 1 place at any time. If it were possible to show focus in multiple components at once, that would not be the 'path of least surprise' for most users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `changeSelection(....)` method is used to select which cell/row has focus. The `addSelectionInterval` is used to select multiple rows.

So the order of code would be:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval(5, 5);
table.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval(3, 3);
table.changeSelection(1, 1, true, false);
```

Comment: the focus is in row but the row will be not selected.

Comment: @kaio, the row is selected for me using JDK8 on Windows 7. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. That is create a JFrame with a Jtable with 10 rows of data and invoke the above 3 statements.

Answer (score 1):

to make focus in row 2 and the two rows 2, 3 are selected, I tried this and it's work:

```
  table.changeSelection(2, 1, true, false);
  table.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval(2, 3);
```